# Integration or unit testing? Testing classes without access to external systems

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Integration tests depends on external systems such as database or network connection. These components should be mock in unit testig.
But when we testing three different classes which behavior depends on each other is this an integretion or unit test? Should that classes be mocked? Lets assume that these classes have no acces to external systems and their behavior is strictly connected.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the terminology varies from company to company.

According to the book "How Google Tests Software" they call tests "Small Tests", "Medium Tests" and "Large Tests", if I remember correctly.
Other companies call it "Whitebox Tests", "Unit Tests", "Integration Tests", "End-to-End Tests". Even though the same name might be used in one company, it could mean something different in another company.

Secondly:
To mock or not to mock depends on what you want to test. If you want to test the interaction of those 3 classes then I suggest using all three as is, unless: If you want to isolate the behaviour of one class or desire a hard-to-achieve-behaviour/unrealistic behaviour/not-yet-implemented-behaviour or it is hard to use the other classes, I suggest mocking the other classes.

Answer (score 2):

As I know.

Purposes of both testing are different from each other. 
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-842-fundamentals-of-systems-engineering-fall-2015/lecture-notes/MIT16_842F15_Ses9_Ver.pdf

But unit testing may support integration testing; If used unit testing framework supports.